# Term for person in a coma

Tags: single-word-requests

The word I'm looking for is just what the title says, a term for a "person in a coma". Or it could be a phrase, because I just need a little variety.

It gets a little repetitive if I say "in a coma" multiple times.

If there isn't any, is there any synonyms for "coma" that communicates similar connotations (like hospital, medical, long time, stability) but not too technical?

Comment: The patient is *comatose.*

Comment: Duplicate? [What is the state in which a person is put to sleep using anaesthesia called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/444413/191178)

Comment: A patient in a coma or not is still a patient. Assign a name and the patient is always *Pat*, as variety is not always a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comatose is the adjective you can substitute: **"a comatose state"**

You can also use "deeply unconscious" or "senseless"

> - [**comatose**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comatose) -   affected with coma.
>   "The patient lay comatose, sustained by respirators."

> - [**unconscious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconscious) having lost consciousness

> - [**senseless**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/senselessness) - unconscious.

The main point is: all comatose patients are unconscious. If their comatose state isn't "superficial" (there's a gradation) they can be totally senseless too. However, not every unconscious or senseless patient is comatose.